# Eclipse Preferences (org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.InstanceScope) : unwanted leading slashes

Tags: java, eclipse, preferences

I want to edit programmaticaly in Java some values of Eclipse InstanceScope preferences.

I use this :

```
Preferences instancePrefsNode = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("my.pref.node");
instancePrefsNode.put("property1", "1");
instancePrefsNode.put("prefix/property2", "2");
```

After flushing i get in the file .metadata\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\my.pref.node.prefs :

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
property1=1
//prefix/property2=2
```

As you can see, the key containing a slash has been prefixed by 2 leading slashes.

I can't get rid off the slash in the name of the property because the property node is defined by an editor of a commercial Eclipse plugin ...

Anyone as an idea on how to supress these 2 leading slashes ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two preference nodes works:

```
  Preferences instancePrefsNode 
           = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("my.pref.node");

  instancePrefsNode.put("property1", "1");

  Preferences instancePrefsNode2 
           = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("my.pref.node/prefix");

  instancePrefsNode2.put("property2", "2");
```

The '//' is used to distinguish between a / in the node and a / in the preference key, so the code you are trying to match must be using two nodes as shown here.